# Does CiviCRM work with Site Performance Engines in Wordpress such as Falcon?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using CiviCRM on Wordpress, and recently installed [Wordfence](http://www.wordfence.com/), an excellent security plugin to make my installation more secure. It also offers the [Faclon Engine](http://docs.wordfence.com/en/Falcon_Cache), a server-side caching system which promises to speed up the website by 30-50 times.

While my installation of CiviCRM isn't too slow, some more speed would be welcome.  However, due to the sometimes complex php searches and apis that CiviCRM runs, I was wondering if it'll lead to mistakes / crashes when running.

Does anyone have a sense if these kinds of engines are ok with CiviCRM or if they're better avoided?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the pages displayed by civicrm can potentially be customised per user (eg. pre-fill the contribution form if the visitor is known or display "looks like you are already registered" on an event page for instance).

So if you start generating a page for one specific visitor, cache it  and distribute the result to all visitors, there is a big risk you will show information about one visitor to all the others, and finetuning which specific page is cache safe is going to be tricky

However, it seems that the falcon cache allow you to explicitly exclude some pages, so you could exclude every civicrm page and still benefit from the cache for all your other pages (eg. your articles).

That's what I'd suggest you to do. The potential speed gain isn't worthwhile the risk of showing private information to the wrong visitor.

Comment: Great, thanks @Xavier. This is what I suspected, but I thought I'd check.

Answer (score 3):

If it helps, we're running with [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/) and it works fine. Civi pages are excluded. It's extremely fast, and the associated lack of PHP processing takes some strain off the server, so there's a corresponding speed bump in Civi too.

(Super Cache used to need [a hack](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/WordPress+plugins+incompatible+with+CiviCRM) to work, but latest versions seem to be ok)

Answer (score 0):

No experience with any of these tools, my recommendation would be to try with a sandbox site first and see what happens.